# Serve dynamically generated xml file to download in Django with character encoding information

Tags: python, xml, django, python-3.x

I need to generate a `XML` file dynamically in `Django` to download.

I can do this with the code below, but without the character encoding information:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def get_xml():
    my_xml = ET.Element('foo', attrib={'bar': 'bla'})
    my_str = ET.tostring(my_xml, 'utf-8', short_empty_elements=False)
    return my_str.decode('utf-8')

# my view
def download_xml_file(request):
    response = HttpResponse(get_xml(), content_type="application/xml")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=myfile.xml'
    return response
```

I can add the character encoding information with the code below, but writing in a file in the server first:

```
def get_xml():
    my_xml = ET.Element('foo', attrib={'bar': 'bla'})
    tree = ET.ElementTree(my_xml)
    fname = 'myfile.xml'
    tree.write(fname, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
    with open(fname, 'r') as fh:
        my_str = fh.read()
    return my_str
```

How do I serve the xml file to download with character encoding information without writing in the server first?

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to solve the question:

1) Concatenate the character encoding information as string (duh!):

```
def get_xml():
    my_xml = ET.Element('foo', attrib={'bar': 'bla'})
    my_str = ET.tostring(my_xml, 'utf-8', short_empty_elements=False)
    enc = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
    return enc += my_str.decode('utf-8')
```

2) Use `xml.dom.minidom.parseString` and `xml.dom.minidom.Node.toxml`:

```
def get_xml():
    my_xml = ET.Element('foo', attrib={'bar': 'bla'})
    my_str = ET.tostring(my_xml, 'utf-8', short_empty_elements=False)
    return xml.dom.minidom.parseString(my_str).toxml(encoding='utf-8')
```